# How to Enable Python3 Support on HDP 2.6

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, anaconda, hortonworks-data-platform

HDP 2.6 (HortonWorks Data Platform) does not support Python3. 
While Python3 (or Anaconda3) are highly appreciated by many Data Scientists.

How to enable Python3 support on HDP 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction are in few files

- /usr/bin/hdp-select
- /etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py

The 2to3 application can be used to convert Python file to support Python3.

```
2to3 -w /usr/bin/hdp-select
2to3 -w /etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py
```

Change a little bit on /etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py to support both Python2 & Python3.

While after these changes, knox are not able to restart.

After doing investigation, although the change makes python code runnable on both Python2 & Python. 
The behavior is slightly different.

The following command will be executed during Knox restart

```
ambari-python-wrapper /usr/bin/hdp-select packages
```

The original script output will be something like

```
Packages:
  accumulo-client
  accumulo-gc

...
```

After 2to3 change, the script output will be something like

```
Packages:
(' ', 'accumulo-client')
(' ', 'accumulo-gc')
```

The two output are certain different. And HDP using these stdout as the interface.

The effect can be nailed down to the following code. The two print statements have different output.

```
pkg = "knox-server"
print " ", pkg

print(" ", pkg)
```

Change the print statement to `print("  ", pkg)` fixed this problem

Comment: Be careful with this. 1. this does not pass changes to other nodes. These scripts must be changes on all nodes if it is to have an effect. 2. With HD Insight, these changes will result in Ambari registerring as broken (despite python3 potentially working), which can result in issues such as Zeppelin integrations failing.

Comment: @Will True. Hope HDP will make those minor change and support both Python2/Python3

Comment: @PaulBendevis which means HDP 3.1.1 still have not support for python2/3

Comment: Although you can use a separate python install for pyspark. Just set the PYSPARK_PYTHON env variable. You don't have to migrate all of Ambari.